# Adding CSS to iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem using iframes, I'm not actually setting a source for the iframe I insert the html I want using jQuery instead which worked fine with me but my actual problem is that I don't know how to include a style sheet to the iframe.

Check the code below:

```
<button id="print1" onclick="  $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html($('#div1').html() + $('#tabs-4').html() + $('#tabs-5').html()+ $('#tabs-6').html() ); window.frames['frame1'].print();">Print full report</button>
<iframe id="frame1" style="visibility:hidden;" height=1px></iframe>
```

Comment: Please define: `include a style sheet to the iframe`

Comment: I want to add a `<link>` tag referring to a CSS file

Answer (score 1):

Inline jQuery, I think wrong.  better have like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#frame1').contents().find('body').html($('#div1').html() + $('#tabs-4').html() + $('#tabs-5').html()+ $('#tabs-6').html() ); 
  window.frames['frame1'].print();
});
</script>
```

Also change your css like below

```
<iframe id="frame1" style="visibility:hidden; height:1px"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's actually working fine with me, the point here is that I want to include a CSS file with iframe for styling the tables added to the iframe

Comment: @Damarawy If you want to add css via jQuery, then you `.css()`.  If you give a specific style we can try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a document source with your iFrame then I believe you should just set css rules directly on the iFrame.  If you need to do it in code then you could simply use $("#frame1").css('myPropertyName', 'myPropertyValue');

Comment: Great we're on track, now I don't want to set each property so I'm asking if there's a way to include a style sheet instead?

Comment: @Damarawy you want to include the entire stylesheet of iframe using jquery?

Comment: The best thing that you can do with this approach is to call .css using this type of syntax...$(this).css({
    "background-color": "yellow",
    "font-weight": "bolder"
  });

Comment: Ok so the browser accepted the script without errors or warnings, but it's not affecting the iframe style at all!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the [iframe](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/iframe.html), use the [jQuery's css function](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
$('#frame1').css({
   'property1': 'value',
   'property2': 'value',
   .
   .
   .
   'propertyN': 'value',
});
```

But you cannot attach a stylesheet to a single element. You'd rather [link to your stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2) in the head element and have in it the style you want for your iframe. E.g.:

```
#frame1 {
    /* Style of the iframe. */
}
```